# indexedDb open onsucess without onupgradeneeded event

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, indexeddb, web-storage

I am seeing that the indexedDb open request's on success callback is called even though the objectStoreNames list is empty.

I believe that the expected behavior is to have "onupgradeneeded" handler being called if objectStorenames.length is zero .

Does any one know why this could be happening ?

[jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/zepehezoco/1/edit?js,console)

```
var db;
var DBOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open("todos", 1);


DBOpenRequest.onerror = function(event) {
  console.error('error in open', event);
};

DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  db = event.target.result;
  var objectStores =  db.objectStoreNames.length;
  console.log('success event, number of objectStores: ' +  objectStores);
};

DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  db = event.target.result;
  var objectStores =  db.objectStoreNames.length;

  console.log('upgradeneeded event, number of objectStores: ' +  objectStores);

  db.createObjectStore("toDoList", { keyPath: "taskTitle" }); 
};
```

Comment: Even though the stores's name list is empty the query is still valid, thus a success, not an error. You have to look at the result on the query in the onsuccess callback.

Comment: I suspect you somehow already have an empty database in Edge with version "1". Change version to "2" and upgradeneeded will probably fire. Or clear your IDB from Edge.

Comment: i am trying to understand if there is a known path that can cause the indexedDb to be in this state.  The problem is resolved if I delete indexedDb database from the browser.

Comment: @John the result object has "name" set to "todos", objectStoreNames is a empty DOMStringList and version=1. "source" and "transaction" fields are null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was another piece of code was calling indexedDB.open, but not listening to upgradeneeded event.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the expected behavior of IndexedDB. You're looking up `db.objectStoreNames.length` inside of `onupgradeneeded`, before the object store has been created. You'll need to check it in the `onsuccess` callback instead.

I also note that the behavior in your jsbin is the same across Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE.